# IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER.DataDirectory has fixed or variable size?

Tags: c, windows, portable-executable

I'm a bit confused about `IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER.DataDirectory`. As [PE/COFF Specification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680547(v=vs.85).aspx) says,

> **Header part:** Data Directories
>
> **Size:** Variable
>
> **Description:** Address/size pairs for special tables that are found in the image file and are used by the operating system (for example, the import table and the export table).

And also

> **NumberOfRvaAndSizes:** The number of data-directory entries in the remainder of the optional header. Each describes a location and size.

And, finally,

> 3.4.3. Optional Header Data Directories (Image Only)
>
> Note that the number of directories is not fixed. Before looking for a specific directory, check the NumberOfRvaAndSizes field in the optional header.
>
> Also, do not assume that the RVAs in this table point to the beginning of a section or that the sections that contain specific tables have specific names.

The last paragraph references the following table:

[image]

As I understand from the above, `DataDirectory` doesn't have to have fixed size of `IMAGE_NUMBEROF_DIRECTORY_ENTRIES`. It should contain `NumberOfRvaAndSizes` entries. Actually this contradicts with the table of directory entries above, where each type has its own offset in the table, and it confuses.

So, my question is: is it allowed to include less than `IMAGE_NUMBEROF_DIRECTORY_ENTRIES` in `DataDirectory` or it must always be that size?

How to properly compute `NumberOfRvaAndSizes` in that case? For example, I have only import directory. Then `NumberOfRvaAndSizes` should be 1. But I will still have 16 entries in `DataDirectory` and import entry at index 1?

*Sorry for some misleading tags. I added them to draw some attention as specifying `portable-executable` only could lead to someone who is familiar with the format could miss the question*

Comment: `is it allowed to include less` - yes. `I have only import directory.` - you need have `NumberOfRvaAndSizes >= 2` in this case because  `IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IMPORT==1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is it allowed to include less than **IMAGE_NUMBEROF_DIRECTORY_ENTRIES** in
>   DataDirectory or it must always be that size?

yes, it allowed. *NumberOfRvaAndSizes* can be any value, including 0

> How to properly compute NumberOfRvaAndSizes in that case?

strange question. simply read and use it - it count of valid entries in *`DataDirectory`* array.

> For example, I have only import directory. Then `NumberOfRvaAndSizes`
>   should be 1.

the *`NumberOfRvaAndSizes`* must be > than max index which you use. because *`IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IMPORT == 1`* - *`NumberOfRvaAndSizes`* must be > 1 - how minimum 2.

and look for [source](https://github.com/mic101/windows/blob/master/WRK-v1.2/base/ntos/rtl/imagedir.c#L180) code for more understand this

Comment: Well, it makes sense. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Address/size pairs for special tables that are found in the image file and are used by the operating system (for example, the import table and the export table).